# Where do Harry and Ginny live after the events of the books?

Tags: harry-potter

We know pretty well the teenage years of Harry up until the death of Voldemort. However I am curious at how would his life be in the immediate aftermath?

We know that

- he joins the ministry under Kingsley as an Auror and will eventually head the department,
- he will occasionnally give some lecture at Hogwarts.

I can imagine that directly after the death of Voldemort, he would stay at the Weasley's for some time. After all, he was only 17 back then. Meanwhile, Ginny will probably go back to Hogwarts​ for her final year. But apart from helping the Order and the new minister to re-build the wizarding community, he would want to start living on his own.

- Is there any information on where does he get to live?
- And does he change place after Ginny moved in with him?

He owned Grimmauld Place, but I can't see him moving there, even with Kreacher more conciliant.

Comment: Given current prices and with three kids I'm pretty sure that's way out of london. Zone 6 at least...

Comment: @JorgeCórdoba, Not sure the same prices apply to Wizards, though. They don't have any commute time, even from hundreds of km away.

Comment: The only bit of evidence I know of is in the Deathly Hallows epilogue. James mentions that he would share a room with Albus in order to allow Teddy Lupin to move in with them (Harry dismisses this idea). This implies that they're in a house with only a few bedrooms, which definitely discounts the idea of Grimmauld Place (which, as you say, he wasn't a huge fan of anyway).

Answer (score 11):

There are a number of scenes in [*Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29056083-harry-potter-and-the-cursed-child) that take place in the Potter family's home. Although it's not stated where it is, we can at least *rule out* a few locations.

It's **definitely not** Godric's Hollow:

> **HERMIONE:** *Godric’s Hollow. It must be twenty years . . .*

Based on the descriptions (and lack of a mention of the location) we can deduce that it's **probably not** 12 Grimmauld Place or 4 Privet Drive.

Comment: Question: How could it possibly be 4 Privet Drive? Presumably the Dursleys would go back there after the war? I know Harry remains on Christmas terms with Dudley. As for 12 Grimmauld how could it be with a ll the dark artefacts that they couldn't get rid of in year 5?

Comment: @Pryftan - I was ruling out known locations

Answer (score 2):

There is no evidence I can find that has him living anywhere. No evidence of any property that the Potter family had. Harry's grandparents obviously lived somewhere before they died, but there is no mention of where that was.

I would think that he lived wherever his grandparents did, or at Grimmauld Place, which probably would have been remodeled first.

It's also possible that they fixed up Potter's Cottage in Godric's Hollow.

I wish I could have found something for you!

Comment: I always wondered if anything happened to his parents' house in Godric's Hollow. I assume it would have been left to Harry - he could potentially have fixed it up and gave it a new life. I do hate to think of it lying there in ruins, years on.

Comment: @Luna I forgot about that as a possible place and i'll add it to the answer but i dont think he would want to lived in the sme place his parents died at and he got his scar.

Comment: I see what you mean, I guess it could go either way with no more information to go of. He may have wanted to leave it, as a shrine to his parents' deaths, or reconstruct it to remember their lives - I think it could have gone either way :)

Comment: Yes I can think he would be somewhat attracted to Godric's Hollow. But his parents' house are used as a shrine. In DH, when he saw it, there was plenty of signatures, and even a magic mark indicating the historical importance of the place. So Godrick's Hollow maybe, but at the same time, we can't say he had happy memories at the place.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin I've read too much fanfiction. I thought that the cottage was owned by Dumbledore and then made a Historical Monument(and thus unalterable). I read the wiki on it after Luna's comment and got my facts straight.

Comment: @Tdmut I think he had every right to take over the house in Godric's Hollow if he wanted to. But, as you say, it was a site of historical significance and the Ministry would've wanted to preserve it for future generations, as they perhaps did for other significant places in Harry's adventures. Hell, for all we know there may be a Harry Potter museum and gift shop there now.

Comment: @TheDarkLord Yes, yes, and it's your fault too! If it wasn't for your wickedness the Potter family wouldn't have been ripped apart, Harry wouldn't have been an orphan, the site wouldn't have become a historical site and many many other beings would not have been done in! Humour aside I think that that's quite probable that he wouldn't want to have removed that significance. I mean he was rather sentimental as the wonderful Severus (who you also cruelly murdered) reminded Potter.

Answer (score -3):

Two houses have been mentioned, Grimmauld Place and Godric's Hollow. The only one I think Harry would have legal claims to is Godric's​ Hollow, the home of his mom and dad.

Yes, Harry was Sirius Black's godson, but that is not a legal title and the only way he could have inherited it is if he was given it in a will. The Black line ended with Sirius and his brother. The two living cousins were sisters, Draco Malfoy's mother Narcissa Black Malfoy and Nimphadora Tonks' mother Andromeda Black Tonks, would have equal clams.

So it looks like Godric's​ Hollow. Or a nice flat in London.

Comment: It is explicit in Chapter Three of *Half-Blood Prince* that Harry inherited everything from Sirius.

Comment: Have you read the books?

Comment: It's definitely not Godric's Hollow based on the (canon) play

Comment: Harry doesn't have a 'mom'. He didn't have one either. He had a mum. But as the others have said in fact Harry *did* inherit everything from Sirius including Kreacher. Unlikely that Harry would want to remove the monument to his family (would you want to do that?) - and I don't see how he could have got rid of the dark artefacts and Sirius's screaming mum from Grimmauld. So it seems to me that neither of those.